# iOS webview can not use history back

Tags: javascript, ios, html, webview

Have anyone used HTML5 history API in mobile webview? I get trouble when using history.back and history.go(-1) on iOS webview, nothing happend when I click a button (everything work fine on Android webview).

```
$(function() {
  $('#back').click(function() {
    history.go(-1); // not working
    history.back(); // not working
  });
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might find better success with `window.history.go(-1);`